# Persisting changes to my dictionary

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm-light

I'm probably missing something obvious due to the late hour.

I have a dictionary defined as such `Dictionary<string,MyObject>` where `MyObject` has a property `bool IsFavoriate`

Initially on page load I query my web service, and update the Dictionary with any new objects and save this in IsolatedStorage.

For the UI, I am binding the Dictionary to an ItemsControl where I have a checkbox:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Categories, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value.IsFavorite}" Content="{Binding Key}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

This binds fine. When I select a checkbox however, I want my Dictionary to update.

Do I perhaps need to have the properties in `MyObject` call `RaisePropertyChanged`? Maybe I'll give that a shot for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `MyObject` class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event from your `IsFavorite` property setter in cases where the latter may be updated programmatically (after the initial population), and you want the `IsChecked` property (and the `CheckBox`’s visual state) to be updated with your changes.

In your case, you want updates to be propagated the other way round (from the `IsChecked` property to `IsFavorite`); that is typically accomplished by setting the binding to `Mode=TwoWay`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Categories, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value.IsFavorite, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Content="{Binding Key}" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

P.S. I’m assuming you meant “When I <strike>select</strike> *check* a checkbox however, I want my Dictionary to update. ”

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I missed the Mode=TwoWay on the actual checkbox vs the ItemsControl... I'll look into that.

Comment: I hadn’t noticed it on the `ItemsSource`. Yes, that’s probably useless.

Comment: That was it. Maybe time for another Red Bull :)